# Does SSRS SDK support SQL Server 2008 (i mean non-express edition)?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have been involved in deploying SSRS SDK ( http://ssrsphp.codeplex.com ) to access Reporting Services for a while now. But whatever tutorials, blogs, working samples I have followed indicate using "SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services edition". Is this SDK only supported in that edition.

At the moment I am using SQL Server 2008 (not the express edition). And all I got till now is this:-

```
Failed to connect to Reporting Service
Make sure that the url (http://localhost:80/reportServer/) and credentials are correct!
```

for the codes:-

```
<?php require_once 'SSRSReport.php';
try{
    $ssrs_report = new SSRSReport(new Credentials(UID, PASWD), SERVICE_URL);
}catch (SSRSReportException $serviceException){
    echo $serviceException->GetErrorMessage();
}?>
```

Although I have properly Setup Reporting Server in my Machine and also my credentials are right; but I  am getting nowhere arround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that it is acutally possible to use SSRSPHP in Enterprise Edition. This library throws exception all the time when the code tries to see if web service URL is OK. See following lines on SSRSReport.php starting at Line 195:

```
$context = stream_context_create($stream_conext_params);
$content = @file_get_contents($executionServiceUrl, false, $context); 
if ($content === FALSE)
    {
        throw new SSRSReportException("",
                    "Failed to connect to Reporting Service  <br/> Make sure " .
                    "that the url ($this->_BaseUrl) and credentials are correct!");
    }
```

You see this exception of "Failed to connect to Reporting Service..." appeared all time for me and others as well. This is unrepairable error. I can explain this but its not the right time. Just let it be like this below and job is done.

```
$context = stream_context_create($stream_conext_params);
$content = @file_get_contents($executionServiceUrl, false, $context);
if ($content === FALSE)
{
    //throw new SSRSReportException("",
      //          "Failed to connect to Reporting Service  <br/> Make sure " .
       //        "that the url ($this->_BaseUrl) and credentials are correct!");
}
```

It works, really! this has been working for me. I hope that does to you too.

Answer (score 1):

you can also put  in the Authentication types of the rsreportserver.config file which is located in the ":\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer."

```
<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsNTLM/>
        <RSWindowsBasic/>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
<Authentication>
```

[reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281309.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Puting <RSWindowsBasic/> in the config is a must since this library SSRSPHP uses Basic HTTP Authentication.

Comment: @MrigeshRajShrestha you can mark it as correct so everyone can see it

Comment: well real reason behind was the issue in SSRSPHP library itself. so this is relevant but not the right answer

Answer (score 0):

several things can be going on.

Can you access http://localhost:80/reportServer/ directly by an URL?  Does it prompt you for a user\password? Is your SSRS instance called default?

Comment: I already got a working version of SSRS. Stable Aspx project already exists to extract the reports; but the question here is if SQL Server 2008 (non express edition) allows to let SSRS SDK work with it. In my opinion its not allowed ; havent got concrete reasoning for that; so presented this question to the community. Thanks for reply

Comment: BY the way I can access  http://localhost:80/reportServer/ directly by an URL; password prompt appears ofcourse; as I have used Windows Authentication for SSRS

Comment: why do you mean by SDK? If you are using php the only options you ahve to interact with SSRS by code are URL access or SOAP. can you be more specific on how you are trying to do it?

Comment: SSRS SDK is name of an opensource project http://ssrsphp.codeplex.com plz check that; I had it specified on Question as well...